# Accessing Form class from other class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been struggling with this bit for over a day now. It appears that many people have asked about similar thing, but they usually want to do something way more advance than what I need. I got an idea what it should look like (I think), but struggle with actually properly implementing it - so here it goes:

I have a form application that does some Odbc, Sql, Csv import/exports.

My main class is the ImportForm class, which contains all the buttons, controls it also creates SQL and ODBC connections in each constructor etc.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        ImportForm importForm = new ImportForm();
        Application.Run(importForm);
    }
```

.

```
    public partial class ImportForm : Form

    public static SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConstantValues.SqlConnectionString);
    public static OdbcConnection odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(ConstantValues.OdbcConnectionString);

    (...)
```

I now have few other classes that do different things. For instance once of imports CSV files into SQL Server. It does it through SqlBulk based on the SQL connection defined in the ImportForm class:

```
internal class CsvImportIntoSql
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection);
```

This, however, returns a syntax error 'The name does not exist in the current context'

I tried:

```
SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(importForm.sqlConnection);
```

But it doesnt work, the class ImportForm is available in the context, but its defined instance importForm is not and I cannot understand why and what I should do to make it work - I have been struggling with that for a while and have to employ different workarounds which often do not make for good code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost right: you need the class name **I**mportForm, not an instance of it ( **i**mportForm) to access a static property:

```
SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ImportForm.sqlConnection);
```

Comment: This worked. I am a tad ashamed I have not tried it myself - just assumed I must need the instance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the CsvImportIntoSql instance is created in the ImportForm, then your best option would be to inject the sqlConnection, or if it is likely to change after the CsvImportIntoSql instance is created then inject a refrence to the CsvImportIntoSql instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you are trying to use the same sqlConnection variable that is defined in another class. but it appears that you have declared this variable as static, which should help while referring to it from another class:

Try to replace

```
SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection);
```

with:

```
SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ImportForm.sqlConnection);
```

This should work. however,using the same connection in multiple instance is not always a good practice. instead, you can initialize a new connection for each job.

Comment: Isnt initializing connections expensive? I thought given that I have only two sources it is a good idea to open them once and keep them open for the entire duration of the program.

Comment: True, It could be bad and expensive if you do it very frequently. but I wouldn't keep the connection open longer than needed. you should close the connection when you are done with the database, and open it again when needed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx